# Accessing global sets from Element API

Tags: plugin-elementapi, globals

Is there an easy way to access global sets from an [Element API](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ElementAPI) endpoint, so its content can be included in the JSON response?

Answer (score 4):

Since Global Sets are elements just like entries, users, etc., you can create API endpoints that are all about them:

```
'globals/<handle:\w+>' => function($handle) {
    return [
        'elementType' => 'GlobalSet',
        'criteria' => ['handle' => $handle],
        'first' => true,
        'transformer' => function(\Craft\GlobalSetModel $globalSet) {
            return [
                'foo' => $globalSet->foo,
                'bar' => $globalSet->bar,
            ];
        }
    ];
}
```

You can also manually query for Global Sets, to include their data in an endpoint that’s tied to another element type:

```
'my/other/endpoint' => [
    'elementType' => 'Entry',
    // ...
    'transformer' => function(\Craft\EntryModel $globalSet) {
        // ...

        // Fetch a global set
        $criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::GlobalSet);
        $criteria->handle = 'myHandle';
        $myGlobalSet = $criteria->first();

        // Include the global set content in the response data
        return [
            // ...
            'foo' => $myGlobalSet->foo,
            'bar' => $myGlobalSet->bar,
        ]
    }
]
```

Craft also provides a couple methods for fetching Global Sets by ID or handle, so if that happens to be exactly what you need, feel free to use those:

- [craft()->globals->getSetById()](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/GlobalsService#getSetById-detail)
- [craft()->globals->getSetByHandle()](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/GlobalsService#getSetByHandle-detail)